# How to show card items in carousel slider with react js?

Tags: reactjs

I want to show some items in carousel slider  with react js. How to render card in carousel slider? I'm unable to find any package to solve this.

Comment: Please see [ask]. How have you tried to solve this yourself? What research have you done? [edit] the question with these details if you h ave them. If you do not, then re-ask later.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can have the carousel slider using libraries like "react-slick". They have an awesome documentation about how to implement and style your own carousel.

https://github.com/akiran/react-slick

Good luck with your project!

Comment: Used React slick, its slick :-)

Answer (score 2):

react-slick will get the job done but its a wrapper around original slick javascript. It is one of the great carousels that do not have real React implementations. Other solutions that not merely a wrapper can be:

> react-responsive-carousel:https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-responsive-carousel
>
> pure-react-carousel: https://www.npmjs.com/package/pure-react-carousel
>
> react-carousel: https://github.com/brainhubeu/react-carousel